# Какой алгоритм используется в libc qsort() в ubuntu ?

Tags: libc, алгоритм, qsort, ubuntu

В ubuntu 10.04 и 11.04 это точно не quicksort.

Эксперименты (вызывал из C и проверял результат) показали устойчивость (stable) сортировки, а оценка дополнительной памяти (смотрел на значение maxresident в выводе /usr/bin/time) предположительно N.

В винде скорее всего quicksort (неустойчивая) и время работы (динамика) (для больших массивов почти одинаковых ключей) похоже на quicksort из 2000-2006 Apple Computer.
Как померять память в винде не знаю.

В Google обыскался, про qsort все что угодно, но все на тему quicksort или как вызывать.

Может быть у кого есть ссылка на исходник (**или готовый ответ**) ?

Comment: А в пакете eglibc-source не смотрели? Ну если пакет -- много, так исходники-то найти недолго.

Comment: Что-то не попалась мне ссылка на исходники. Видимо не так ищу.

Comment: **Ну почему оба ответа и один комментарий нельзя отметить правильными ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Можете скачать исходник с сайта Ubuntu. Называется eglibs. qsort находится в файле stdlib/qsort.c. Щас взглянул. Для больший объемов используется быстрая сортировка, для непревышающих опеределенный порог, задаваемый константой MAX_THRES, используется сортировка вставкой. В моей версии MAX_THRES=4. Она используется как промежуточная при быстрой сортировке.

Но это все, естественно, не определено никаким стандартом и может меняться в разных версиях библиотеки.

Comment: Ссылочку (URL) положите. Но, судя по Вашему описанию это стандартный quicksort из glibc (у него еще точка входа 

    void
_quicksort (void *const pbase, size_t total_elems, size_t size,
     __compar_fn_t cmp)

       Written by Douglas C. Schmidt (schmidt@ics.uci.edu).

Answer (score 1):

[Log of /trunk/libc/stdlib/qsort.c](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/libc/stdlib/qsort.c?view=log). Это лог, ссылки на текст - внутри.

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо ! Код увидел, попозже посмотрю внимательно, но на первый взгляд очередной quicksort.

Comment: А что Вы там ожидали увидеть? Timsort?

Comment: Спасибо @alexlz и @mikillskegg, да **eglibc-source** похоже это те исходники, файл stdlib/msort.c комплексная сортировка (смесь mergesort и quicksort) с интерфейсами qsort и qsort_r.


Timsort ? Нет, хотя Timsort хороший (но не очень понятный алгоритм) устойчивый, шустрый (вообще видимо лучше qsort) и дополнительной памяти от меньше 1/4 N берет (хотя больше 1/8). 

Наверное его тоже стоит запрограммировать на C с интерфейсом qsort.

Вообще (в свободное время) пытаюсь сделать mergesort почти без дополнительной памяти (очередь из блоков в освобождающейся при слиянии  памяти).